# Buttons on Navbar not aligned in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using the navbar from bootstrap 5. I having an UI issue.

#### What do I have?

This is the navbar I am currently having.
[image]

#### What do I want?

I want to align the navbar buttons (Login and Signup) to the right end.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = (props) => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    console.log("hello");
    navigate("/login");
    props.showAlert("User Logged Out succesfully! ", "info");
    
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
            Navbar
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>

            {!localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
              <form className="d-flex">
                <Link
                  className="btn btn-outline-success mx-2"
                  to="/signup"
                  role="button"
                >
                  SignUp
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className="btn btn-outline-success"
                  to="/login"
                  role="button"
                >
                  Login
                </Link>
              </form>
            ) : (
              <form className="d-flex">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-outline-success mx-2"
                  onClick={handleLogout}
                >
                  LogOut
                </button>
              </form>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I have tried many attempts but still, it is not working. I am using bootstrap built-in classes also.

Comment: Did you try [float](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)?

Comment: No, I tried only  `margin-inline-start`

Comment: I don't see this in your code. Can you update the post with what you have tried? Also, can you try once with float?

Comment: float not working. I tried `margin-inline-start` using chrome dev tools

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add a `me-auto` class with `<ul>` as given `<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = (props) => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    console.log("hello");
    navigate("/login");
    props.showAlert("User Logged Out succesfully! ", "info");
    
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
            Navbar
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto"> 
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>

            {!localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
              <form className="d-flex">
                <Link
                  className="btn btn-outline-success mx-2"
                  to="/signup"
                  role="button"
                >
                  SignUp
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className="btn btn-outline-success"
                  to="/login"
                  role="button"
                >
                  Login
                </Link>
              </form>
            ) : (
              <form className="d-flex">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-outline-success mx-2"
                  onClick={handleLogout}
                >
                  LogOut
                </button>
              </form>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: what error are you facing can you please show here?

Comment: Its just `className` to be replaced with `class`

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add `me-auto` in `<ul>` like this:

```
<ul className="navbar-nav me-auto">
```

[image]